# How to handle twitch passport.js auth code?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, twitch

I'm trying to build a simple app that authenticates a twitch account and displays a users information. I'm stuck with how to send along my auth code once a user has successfully logged in.

Server-side, my code looks like this:

```
---auth-routes.js

// auth with twitch
router.get("/twitch", passport.authenticate("twitch", { scope: "user_read" }), (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({message: 'Authenticating...'});
    console.log('Authenticating...')
});

// redirect to home page after successful login via twitch
router.get(
    "/twitch/redirect",
    passport.authenticate("twitch", {
        successRedirect: "/auth/twitch/redirect",
        failureRedirect: "/auth/login/failed"
    }) 
);


---config/passport-setup.js

// Override passport profile function to get user profile from Twitch API
OAuth2Strategy.prototype.userProfile = function(accessToken, done) {
    var options = {
      url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Client-ID': TWITCH_ID,
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
      }
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (response && response.statusCode == 200) {
        done(null, JSON.parse(body));
      } else {
        done(JSON.parse(body));
      }
    });
  }

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user);
  });

  passport.use('twitch', new OAuth2Strategy({
      authorizationURL: 'https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize',
      tokenURL: 'https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token',
      clientID: TWITCH_ID,
      clientSecret: TWITCH_SECRET,
      callbackURL: TWITCH_CB,
      state: true
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      profile.accessToken = accessToken;
      profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;
      console.log(profile);



      // Securely store user profile in your DB
      //User.findOrCreate(..., function(err, user) {
      //  done(err, user);
      //});

      done(null, profile);
    }
  ))
```

I also have a simple profile component that displays when auth/twitch/redirect route is hit

```
export const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
                <Route path='/auth/twitch/redirect' component={Profile} />
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

According to the twitter documentation, you need to take the access code appended to your redirect URI and make a post request with it. I'm having trouble figuring out how and where to pull that code and send it along. Here's what they say in the documentation:

> In our example, your user gets redirected to:

```
http://localhost/?code=394a8bc98028f39660e53025de824134fb46313
    &scope=viewing_activity_read
    &state=c3ab8aa609ea11e793ae92361f002671
```

> 3) On your server, get an access token by making this request:

```
POST https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token
    ?client_id=<your client ID>
    &client_secret=<your client secret>
    &code=<authorization code received above>
    &grant_type=authorization_code
    &redirect_uri=<your registered redirect URI>
```

> Here is a sample request:

```
POST https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token
    ?client_id=uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2
    &client_secret=nyo51xcdrerl8z9m56w9w6wg
    &code=394a8bc98028f39660e53025de824134fb46313
    &grant_type=authorization_code
    &redirect_uri=http://localhost
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggeling with the same problem. However, I think I might help a little bit.
I also see that this is a bit old post so you might have figured it out already.
To get the hash or fragment from the URL using router, you can:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const yourCallbackComponent = () => {

  let location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location)
  }, [location])

  return ()
}
```

I wrote this in a hurry, sorry if it's bad. But when a route is loaded you can extract information in the location object.

The expected output of the console.log should be somewhere near this:

```
{
  key: 'ac3df4', // not with HashHistory!
  pathname: '/somewhere',
  search: '?access_token:jf82rjfj02f0f',
  hash: '#access_tokenjf82rjfj02f0f',
  state: {
    [userDefined]: true
  }
}
```

It's either in the hash or search, depending on what you get back from twitch.
Hope this helps if you didn't find a solution already.

I'm still trying to figure out the next steps myself so I can't be of any assistance there.
Let me know if you're still stuck, then I'll post my findings when I figure out how this works.